# Structuring a for loop to output classifier predictions in python

Tags: loops, dataframe

I have an existing .py file that prints a classifier.predict for a SVC model.  I would like to loop through each row in the X feature set to return a prediction.

I am currently trying to define the element from which to iterate over so as to allow for definition of the test statistic feature set X.

The test statistic feature set X is written in code as:
     X_1 = xspace.iloc[testval-1:testval, 0:5]

testval is the element name used in the for loop in the above line:

```
 for testval in X.T.iterrows():
 print(testval)
```

I am having trouble returning a basic set of index values for X (X is the pandas dataframe)

I have tested the following with no success.

```
 for index in X.T.iterrows():
 print(index)

 for index in X.T.iteritems():
 print(index)
```

I am looking for the set of index values, with base 1 if possible, like 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...n

seemingly simple stuff...i haven't located an existing question via stackoverflow or google.

ALSO, the individual dataframes I used as the basis for X were refined with the line:

```
 df1.set_index('Date', inplace = True)
```

Because dates were used as the basis for the concatenation of the individual dataframes the loops as written above are returning date values rather than 
location values as I would prefer hence:

```
 X_1 = xspace.iloc[testval-1:testval, 0:5]
```

where iloc, location is noted

please ask for additional code if you'd like to see more

the loops i've done thus far are returning date values, I would like to return index values of the location of the rows to accommodate the line:

```
 X_1 = xspace.iloc[testval-1:testval, 0:5]
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop structure below seems to be working for my application.

```
 i = 1
 j = list(range(1, len(X),1)

 for i in j:
```